# Fast forward and Backward in VLC player with Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, vlc, fast-forward

I use VLC player in my movie app. I can play video and adjust video volume. 
 I would like to make Fast Forward and Backward with the speed of 2x, 3x, 4x. 
 I really don't know how to implement this. :( 
Could anyone help me? I already search examples in google. I don't found it yet.

Comment: Use the [ and ] keys to speed up or slow down.

Comment: @May Phyu Hi, am having same issue. if have solved your issue can please post answer

Comment: @MuseerAnsari, I gave up that process bro. :D

Comment: @MayPhyu me too. hehehe

Comment: @MayPhyu how you solved this?